# Cannot change geo-permissions in Twilio console

Tags: twilio

My attempts to send messages are being blocked by geo-permissions, with error 21408.

I can access the geo-permissions panel, but I am not able to make any changes. By default, there are no countries selected, not even the US, where the purchased phone number is from. Options to add countries to the geo-permissions section are greyed out.

Is this due to permissions restrictions on my account? I am operating under a developer sub-account of my client. The console offers no hint of why I am not able to make these changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue is that you indeed are a developer and not an admin on that sub account. If this is work for a client I would ask that the admin change any geo-permissions for you.

Comment: How to verify if I'm develop or admin of a Twilio sub account?

Comment: I just figured it out. You need to click on `View all account` to view your role where you switch between subacounts.